# layoutparams is not honored when using addView

Tags: android

```
swipeToRefresh.addView(webView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
```

Basically my webview is added to swipeToRefresh. I try to set the height here to be 1, but my webview still fill the entire screen.

swipeToRefresh is a subclass of `SwipeRefreshLayout` and is using `match_parent` in both width and height. Any idea how can I know why the height is not used? How to know why is it changed?

Comment: `SwipeRefreshLayout` doesn't consider its child's `LayoutParams`. It basically just lays out the child to fill, minus padding: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/swiperefreshlayout/swiperefreshlayout/src/main/java/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java#687.

Comment: `SwipeRefreshLayouts`'s docs actually mention it, too: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout#:~:text=will%20be%20forced%20to%20match%20both%20the%20width%20and%20the%20height%20supplied%20in%20this%20layout.